# H1 won't center with a set width

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center an h1 tag, but it doesn't work when I set it's width. When I don't set a specific width it works, but I would like to keep the width at 400. My code is below.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.navbar-ul {
    margin: 0;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 10px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: -1px 10px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: -1px 10px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

a {
    color: white;
}

li, a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    transition: 1s;
    border: solid 1px transparent;
}

li:hover, li:hover a {
    background-color: #3f3f3f;
}

.header-text {
    border: solid 5px black;
    width: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 25px;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Dark Website Template by Jordan Baron</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles-main.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="navbar">
            <ul class="navbar-ul">
                <strong><li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li></strong>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <strong><h1 class="header-text">DARK</h1></strong>
        
    </body>
    
</html>
```

I don't think the other elements are the problem, but hey, it's a possibility.

Comment: How can you expect it to center across the screen if it has a set width of 400px? As is it is properly centering for its given width. If you want to center that h1 across the screen you will need to make width: 100%;

Answer (score 2):

The `h1`-element is a block-element. This means that the width is `100%` by default. By using `text-align: center` you only center the text inside the element, not the `h1` itself.

When you set the width to `400px` the text is still centered inside the block, but the element itself no longer has a full-width.

The solution would be to center the element as a whole. This can be done by setting the horizontal `margin` to `auto`.

This should work for you:

```css
.header-text {
  border: solid 5px black;
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="header-text">DARK</h1>
```

For more information about centering with CSS, check out this guide: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to center the entire element, you can use the `auto` value for the left and right margin on the header:

```
.header-text {
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```